# Why can't Typesafe Activator UI see routes from subproject but activator can?

Tags: playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I am testing the Activator-UI (v1.2.6) with Play Framework 2.3.2.

I compile and run the app but I get a no route found with only the routes of the base app shown on the error page in the UI.

The app works fine when I run using `activator` from command line, so not really a blocker for me. But I thought it's a great feature to have for discussions etc where I can access source code from the browser using activator.

Not sure what I need to add to my `build.sbt` in order to rectify this from the activator-ui.

Comment: The UI doesn't support multi-project builds yet.  Coming soon (TM).